# PHP Fatar Error: call to a member function make() in index.php on line 50 Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, internal-server-error

I am getting below error :-

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function make() on string in /home/karaoke/web/example.com/public_html/index.php on line 50
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/karaoke/web/example.com/public_html/index.php:0
```

My laravel `public/index.php` is as it was default.

Certain points :-

1. This site is working fine in localhost
2. But, same site is not working on server.

## Things i have already done and tried :

1. Checked chmod of all file and folder.
   2.. `storage` directory and directory/files is writable.
2. Cross checked index.php file already 10 time now and see no error.
3. files are perfectly readable in index.php file and no file is missing nor any file is missing to open.

I am running Centos 6.8 with php version 5.6. My Laravel version is 5.2

My index.php if some one needs them :-

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylorotwell@gmail.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels nice to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Comment: Adding code would be helpful. Without it.. digging into my installation, line 50 is `$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);`, and the app declaration is `$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`. Have you modified your app.php at all?

Comment: added index.php code

Comment: What's about ```vendor``` folder, exists? have you tried to composer update?

Comment: vendor folder is already there. I just zip > upload > unzip it from my localhost to server.

Comment: You could try using composer to install the vendor instead of zipping and uploading it.

Comment: Just did composer thing and everything is working fine now :) could you please add as this an answer. Though i did before comment, but i would be happy if some one gets solved too :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error indicates that the `make()` method on line 50

```
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);
```

is not called on an object. Normally your `$app` variable would hold an instance of `Illuminate\Foundation\Application`.
It does that via `require`ing `__DIR__.'/../bootstrap/app.php';`.

Please check if the file `bootstrap/app.php` is present and has the right content.

Answer (score 0):

`$app->run($app->make('request'));`

you can try to add this in you `public/index.php`