# Laravel: Call to a member function make() on null

Tags: php, laravel, homestead

For complicated reasons, I'm trying to get a Laravel project running that I did not develop. I'm using a Vagrant/Homestead combination (Host Windows 10, VM Homestead v2.1.8 (Ubuntu 18.04.1) with Laravel  5.0.35, PHP 5.6 - that's what it was created in) and after putting the project there and running composer install, I just tried to have a look at the routes via

```
php artisan route:list
```

which gave me the error

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function make() on null in /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php on line 4823
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/artisan:0
PHP   2. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/artisan:36
PHP   3. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php:94
PHP   4. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:126
PHP   5. Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:195
PHP   6. Illuminate\Console\Command->run() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:874
PHP   7. Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:101
PHP   8. Illuminate\Console\Command->execute() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/symfony/console/Symfony/Component/Console/Command/Command.php:257
PHP   9. Illuminate\Container\Container->call() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Command.php:115
PHP  10. call_user_func_array:{/home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:964}() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:964
PHP  11. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->fire() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:964
PHP  12. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRoutes() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:75
PHP  13. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getRouteInformation() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:89
PHP  14. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getMiddleware() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:109
PHP  15. Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteListCommand->getControllerMiddleware() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:142
PHP  16. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/RouteListCommand.php:161
PHP  17. Illuminate\Container\Container->make() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:1543
PHP  18. Illuminate\Container\Container->build() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:1019
PHP  19. Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:1081
PHP  20. Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:1095
PHP  21. Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:1111
PHP  22. Illuminate\Container\Container->make() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:1543
PHP  23. Illuminate\Container\Container->fireResolvingCallbacks() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:1029
PHP  24. Illuminate\Container\Container->fireCallbackArray() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:1180
PHP  25. Illuminate\Validation\ValidationServiceProvider->Illuminate\Validation\{closure}() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:1195
PHP  26. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest->validate() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:4699
PHP  27. Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest->getValidatorInstance() /home/vagrant/code/newbackend/vendor/compiled.php:4772
```

The error leads me to

```
$factory = $this->container->make('Illuminate\\Validation\\Factory');
```

in class FormRequest (extends Request implements ValidatesWhenResolved) on line 4823 in vendor/compiled.php - but that's not telling me much.

As I'm new to Php/laravel and don't quite have a handle on the intricacies of this project, my googling efforts left me more confused than ever. Does anyone have at least a starting point for me on how to resolve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Fatar Error: call to a member function make() in index.php on line 50 Laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37998378/php-fatar-error-call-to-a-member-function-make-in-index-php-on-line-50-larave)

Comment: As a side note, if you are new to PHP, I would discourage you to use Laravel. First familiarise yourself with PHP, OOP and them Laravel.

Comment: Updated to show line that threw error (yup, should have been there from beginning). Yes, there's a lot I have to learn - unfortunately, I don't have a choice about Laravel, kinda got thrown into it, and it might just be that this is easily fixable, and I just don't see it (yet).

Comment: In that case I would suggest having a look at: https://laracasts.com/series/php-for-beginners and https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-from-scratch-2018